# Trailing spaces when copying from gnome-terminal using zsh

Tags: terminal, zsh, gnome-terminal, copy-paste, whitespace

When copying text from `gnome-terminal` with `zsh` trailing whitespace is also copied. For example copying the following clearly adds a vertical scollbar on stackexchange site as trailing whitespace the width of the terminal is included:

```
$ echo $0                                                                                                                                            
zsh
```

If I drop into `bash` this does not happen *(no spaces, no scrollbar)*:

```
$ echo $0
bash
```

Is there an option with `zsh` to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have $RPS1 variable set (I have current directory there). If you just unset it with

```
unset RPS1
```

then trailing whitespace should disappear.

Comment: If your $TERM is set correctly, likely adding `-256color` , you can keep your $RPS1 set.